# How to get affected rows in ASP Classic JScript?

Tags: asp-classic, adodb, jscript

I have the following script in ASP Classic:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE=Javascript%>
<%
    var dataConn = Server.CreateObject('ADODB.Connection');
    dataConn.Open(connectionString);
    var rowsAffected;
    dataConn.Execute(command, rowsAffected);
    Response.Write(rowsAffected);
    dataConn.Close();
%>
```

When executing the script rowsAffected is undefined. How to get the affected rows?

Comment: where is `command` defined?

Comment: It's any SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE statement. Not important here.

Comment: In addtion: When I tried the same in VBScript, I get -1 for rowsAffected.

Comment: Also, that's JScript, not JavaScript. don't let the fact you can use the [`@LANGUAGE` directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524311(v=vs.90).aspx) as JavaScript fool you it's just an alias for JScript.

Comment: You can mix languages in the same asp file...

Answer (score 0):

After searching the web I found an answer that JScript does not support ByRef variables to get the affected rows. It only works in VBScript.

So I use the following script to get the affected rows from my stored procedure:

```
<!--METADATA TYPE="TypeLib" NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.6 Library" UUID="{00000206-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}" VERSION="2.6" -->
<%@ LANGUAGE=JScript%>
<%
    var cn = Server.CreateObject('ADODB.Connection');
    var cs = '...';
    cn.Open(cs); cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient;

    var cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command");
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = '...';
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc;

    cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter('@ID', adInteger, adParamInput, 4, id));
    cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter('@RowCount', adInteger, adParamOutput, 4));

    cmd.Execute(adExecuteNoRecords);
    Response.Write(cmd.Parameters('@RowCount').Value);

    cn.Close();
%>
```

And you need a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.<StoredProcedure> @ID int, @RowCount int = 0 output AS BEGIN

    [...]

    SET @RowCount = @@rowcount;

END
```